# linux shell: why zero ending line dont work as expected?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I've read the "man" about grep, and when I try the "classical" way it works, whereas when I try using zero-ending lines, it doesn't work:

```
/cygdrive/g/eb # find . -type f | grep -E 'pdf$'
./Je_vais_mieux.pdf
./La_delicatesse.pdf
./Femme.pdf
./Souvenirs.pdf
/cygdrive/g/eb # find . -type f -print0 | grep -ZE 'pdf$'
Binary file (standard input) matches
/cygdrive/g/eb # find . -type f -print0 | grep -zE 'pdf$'
Binary file (standard input) matches
/cygdrive/g/eb # find . -type f -print0 | grep -ZzE 'pdf$'
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `grep -a`, to tell `grep` that its input is in fact textual in nature:

```
find . -type f -print0 | grep -E -Zz -a 'pdf$'
```

That said, this is a silly thing to do, as `find` can filter its own output by suffix without help from grep:

```
find . -name '*pdf' -type f -print0
```